# jquery ajax done cannot access returned object property

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

**SOLVED!**

Solution:
Bind **this** to the callback

```
this.loadVideo(this.reloadVideo.bind(this));
```

I'm solving quite strange behavior of jquery.

I have object, where is method returning ajax response. Problem is, that I cannot access returned object property.

When I try to access returned object data:

```
console.log(this.actualVideoData.htmlContent);
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.actualVideoData.htmlContent')
```

Do you have any idea, why I cannot access **this.actualVideoData.htmlContent** ? Thank you for your responses.

jQuery method object, which is handling this is there:

```
var VideoControls = function () {

    this.loadVideoUrl = window.loadVideoUrl;
    this.mainVideoWrapp = $('#main-video-wrapp');
    this.actualVideoData;
    this.actualVideoId;

    if (!(this instanceof VideoControls)) {
        return new VideoControls();
    }

};
VideoControls.prototype = {
        reloadVideo: function(data){
            console.log(this);
            console.log(this.actualVideoData.htmlContent);
            //this.mainVideoWrapp.html(this.actualVideoData.htmlContent);
        },
        changeVideo: function (videoId) {
            this.actualVideoId = videoId;
            this.loadVideo(this.reloadVideo());
        }, loadVideo: function (callback) {
            var self = this;
            if (typeof this.loadVideoUrl !== 'undefined') {

                var postData = {
                    video_id: this.actualVideoId,
                    _token: getCsrfToken()
                };

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: this.loadVideoUrl,
                    data: postData
                }).done(function (data) {
                    self.actualVideoData = data.video;
                    if (typeof callback === 'function') {
                        callback()
                    }

                });
            }
        }
    };
```

Here is, what I get, when I call console.log(data);

```
Object
video: Object
htmlContent: "<article id="video">↵    <div class="r-iframe-wrapp">↵        <iframe width="900" height="506" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/cHUT25erCas" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>↵    </div>↵    <header>↵        <a href="#" class="title"><h1>Ben Cristovao &amp; Cavalier - Tezky Vahy [Prod. Jan Sokolowski ] Gladiator Treninkova Hymna</h1></a>↵        <div><span class="show-full-description collapse-toggle toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#video-description">Zobrazit celý popis videa</span></div>↵        <div id="video-description" class="video-desc collapse opened">↵            <div class="video-sub-header clearfix">↵                <div class="left">↵                    Publikoval: <strong>Ben Cristovao</strong> 19. 10. 2014 v 19:01↵                </div>↵                <div class="right video-visits-counter">↵                                    </div>↵            </div>↵            <div class="desc-text">↵                Barbaři: https://www.facebook.com/thebarbarianlife↵Cavalier: https://www.facebook.com/cavaliercz↵Negr: https://www.facebook.com/cristovao.ben↵Producent: https://www.facebook.com/sokolowski.jan↵↵            </div>↵        </div>↵    </header>↵</article>"
videoId: "1"
__proto__: Object
__proto__: Object
```

Here is, what I get, when I call console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

```
[Log] {"video":{"htmlContent":"<article id=\"video\">\n    <div class=\"r-iframe-wrapp\">\n        <iframe width=\"900\" height=\"506\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/cHUT25erCas\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>\n    </div>\n    <header>\n        <a href=\"#\" class=\"title\"><h1>Ben Cristovao &amp; Cavalier - Tezky Vahy [Prod. Jan Sokolowski ] Gladiator Treninkova Hymna</h1></a>\n        <div><span class=\"show-full-description collapse-toggle toggle\" data-toggle=\"collapse\" data-target=\"#video-description\">Zobrazit celý popis videa</span></div>\n        <div id=\"video-description\" class=\"video-desc collapse opened\">\n            <div class=\"video-sub-header clearfix\">\n                <div class=\"left\">\n                    Publikoval: <strong>Ben Cristovao</strong> 19. 10. 2014 v 19:01\n                </div>\n                <div class=\"right video-visits-counter\">\n                                    </div>\n            </div>\n            <div class=\"desc-text\">\n                Barbaři: https://www.facebook.com/thebarbarianlife\nCavalier: https://www.facebook.com/cavaliercz\nNegr: https://www.facebook.com/cristovao.ben\nProducent: https://www.facebook.com/sokolowski.jan\n\n            </div>\n        </div>\n    </header>\n</article>","videoId":"1"}}
```

Response for this:

```
console.log(this);
console.log(this.htmlContent);
console.log($(this).actualVideoData.htmlContent);
```

Are:

```
Object
actualVideoId: "1"
loadVideoUrl: "http://favideo.inovestudio.com/ajax/video/load"
mainVideoWrapp: Object[1]
__proto__: Object

undefined

TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '$(this).actualVideoData.htmlContent')
```

This is strange behavior. Also - I tried to do `console.log(data)` in $.ajax.done, before calling the callback and it doesn't log into console anything. So I think, function reloadVideo is calling before `self.actualVideoData = data.video` is done or smth like this.

Other strange thing: When I call `console.log(this)` in

```
reloadVideo
```

method, it return **window** object

Also - when I do: **console.log(data.video.htmlContent)** in **.done()** it works fine. So probably, problem is in accessing **this** in **reloadVideo** method. But I don't have any idea, why.

Comment: Try wrapping `$.ajax` within `$.when` like -> `$.when($.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: this.loadVideoUrl,
                    data: postData
                })).done(function(data)...`

Comment: Now it doesn't return error `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.actualVideoData.htmlContent')` but it return, that value is undefined.

Comment: What you will get in `data` within `reloadVideo: function(data){` and also just try `this.htmlContent` or `$(this).actualVideoData.htmlContent`

Comment: Use `data.htmlContent` since `console.log(data)` shows what it contains as `object`..

Comment: Edit my first question. Problem is, that in reloadVideo method is in `this` stored `window` object.